# Writing dynamic query for getting values from two tables using join in criteria builder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables member and cases.Member table has many to one relation to intake case. I have to fetch all the details from the member table and casenumber from the case table. I have to add conditions like casenumber like "%hada%" and also from the meber table. I am planning to use the criteria builder. Can anyone suggest me a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the internet. Do give it a try and let us know if  there is any issues. Here is one https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: I have tried the method suggested in the link but now I am getting this error.
required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found

I am new to Spring and JPA .Please anyone suggest any approach.